# How do you handle query parameters of the form "hub.challenge" in dart lang using RPC?

Tags: dart, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, dart-rpc

Typically query parameters get mapped to optional variables in dart lang using rpc.

For example http://www.exampleurl.com/test?filter=1

> Future test({int filter})

Gets mapped to filter.

However if it is http://www.exampleurl.com/test?hub.challenge=1.  There appears to be no way to retrieve that query parameter.  This is significant because it's required for verification with Facebook's Messenger API.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like `package:rpc` supports this yet. You should [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc/issues/new).

Comment: I logged an issue with RPC package on github